# Create Custom Types File And Use Angular 2 Types With It

Tags: types, typescript, angular

Im struggling to see how to reference angular2 types inside my custom_typings.d.ts file.

So far I've tried:

**importing**: `import {Control} from 'angular2/common'`

**referencing**: `///<reference path='../typings/main/definitions/angular2/angular2.d.ts' />'`

All that happens is my typescript compiler fails with a ton of errors.  How would you create your custom types with angular types included?

Looking to do something like this:

```
declare module mg {

  export interface IStageForm {
    dept: Control; // This is an angular type 
  }

}
```

Its also worth noting I am using an angular 2 webpack boilerplate that uses 'typings' for its type management.  Am I missing something obvious here?

**Also using `import * as common from 'angular2/common' lets me reference the type i need, but then typescript compiler fails saying it can't find my module "mg" that the type is used inside of**

Comment: importing Control from common should be enough. Add `moduleResolution: node` in your tsconfig.json, that way it will be able to discover angular2 typings.

Comment: Added that OK, but then everywhere in my app I reference my module "mg" it errors now saying it cannot find that namespace.  Is there more to it that I'm missing?